# how to design a lockscreen using swift?

Tags: ios, lockscreen

Is it possible to customize the lock screen in iOS at all ? I have looked up sources like git and stack-overflow with little to no response.

My project is to build a customized lock screen app. Any guidance in the right path would be greatly appreciated.

Just display pictures on the lock screen

Answer (score 0):

You can change the picture on the lock screen via Settings / Wallpaper.  It is not possible to change the software that implements the phone locking mechanism.